# using python urlopen for a url query

Tags: python, http, url

Using `urlopen` also for url queries seems obvious. What I tried is:

```
import urllib2
query='http://www.onvista.de/aktien/snapshot.html?ID_OSI=86627'
f = urllib2.urlopen(query)
s = f.read()
f.close()
```

However, for this specific url query it fails with HTTP error 403 forbidden
When entering this query in my browser, it works.
Also when using http://www.httpquery.com/ to submit the query, it works.

Do you have suggestions how to use Python right to grab the correct response?

Comment: Your browser might be sending cookies in the HTTP request. Extract the cookies from the browser's cookie jar, and pass them to `urlopen`. You may want to use the NextExport extension of Firebug to save the exact HTTP requests your browser has sent recently. If you replay them exactly from Python, it usually works.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it requires cookies... (which you can do with urllib2), but an easier way if you're doing this, is to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
r = session.get('http://www.onvista.de/aktien/snapshot.html?ID_OSI=86627')
```

This is generally a much easier and less-stressful method of retrieving URLs in Python.

`requests` will automatically store and re-use cookies for you. Creating a session is slightly overkill here, but is useful for when you need to submit data to login pages etc..., or re-use cookies across a site... etc...

**using urllib2 is something like**

```
import urllib2, cookielib

cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies) )
data = opener.open('url').read()
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the urllib2 default user agent is banned by the host. You can simply supply your own user agent string:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.onvista.de/aktien/snapshot.html?ID_OSI=86627'
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"User-Agent" : "MyUserAgent"})
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
print contents
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Anonymous Coward, this does the trick. And analyzing the contents using BeautifulSoup also works. Great!